# Fatal Python error: _PyMem_DebugMalloc: Python memory allocator called without holding the GIL

Tags: python, cpython

I'm learning cpython, version [3.9.0b1](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.9.0b1), but recently my learning has been interrupted by a [Python Fatal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFnEw.png) not allowing python interpreter to work at all

**Here is what the Python Fatal Error says:**

```
hatim@hatim-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/cpython$ ./python

Python 3.11.0a3+ (heads/main-dirty:6ca78affc8, Jan 19 2022, 11:14:50) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> print()

Fatal Python error: _PyMem_DebugMalloc: Python memory allocator called without holding the GIL

Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007f99b0867280 (most recent call first):
 
 <no Python frame>

[1]    3660 abort (core dumped)  ./python
```

**How I compile Python**

A friend of mine (git clone)d the source for me, I renamed to as **cpython.zip**

I extract the source to directory named **cpython**

**cd ~/home/hatim/cpython**

**1. in files configure, config.guess, config.sub I remove a space placed in theirs shebangs because this space generates this error**

***zsh: ./configure: bad interpreter: /bin/sh^M: no such file or directory***

**All 3 files have this shebang: #! /bin/sh**

**There is a space between ! and /**

**2. find | xargs -I f dos2unix f**

**3. autoconf**

**4. ./configure --with-pydebug**

**5. make, recently I add -j**

**6. make -j altinstall**

**so that this version does not interfere with my other pythons**

This **Python Fatal Error** never showed up before even though I compiled this same cpython on my computer more than 10 times but it only happened yesterday. I thought maybe I broke cpython code, but I deleted the whole (cpython) directory and unzipped the source and re-compiled it but the Fatal Error kept showing up

I do not know much, but I tried to trace where the problem lies, and here is what I know:

This Fatal Error is caused by **_PyMem_DebugCheckGIL in cpython/Objects/obmalloc.c** which raises this error when **PyGILState_Check, in cpython/Python/pystate.c**, returns 0

```
in file cpython/Objects/obmalloc.c
int PyGILState_Check(void)
{
    
    struct _gilstate_runtime_state *gilstate = &_PyRuntime.gilstate;

    if (!gilstate->check_enabled) {

        printf("\n!gilstate->check_enabled\n");

        return 1;

    }

    if (!PyThread_tss_is_created(&gilstate->autoTSSkey)) {

        printf("\n!PyThread_tss_is_created(&gilstate->autoTSSkey)\n");

        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d", (gilstate != NULL));

    PyThreadState *tstate = _PyRuntimeGILState_GetThreadState(gilstate);

    if (tstate == NULL) {

        printf("\ntstate == NULL\n");

        return 0;

    }

    return (tstate == _PyGILState_GetThisThreadState(gilstate));
}
```

```
in file cpython/Python/pystate.c
static inline void
_PyMem_DebugCheckGIL(const char *func)
{
    if (!PyGILState_Check()) {
        _Py_FatalErrorFunc(func,
                           "Python memory allocator called "
                           "without holding the GIL");
    }
}
```

**in my case PyGILState_Check returns 0 because tstate is NULL**

I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit

So, what to do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning cpython, version 3.9.0b1

No, you're not. Your trace clearly says

```
Python 3.11.0a3+ (heads/main-dirty:6ca78affc8
```

which means you're using a version of Python based on [6ca78affc8](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/6ca78affc8), then modified in the working tree (`-dirty`).

> A friend of mine (git clone)d the source for me, I renamed to as cpython.zip

Why didn't you clone the source yourself, or at least use a [source tarball](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3102/)? If you had to change newlines around, it sounds like your friend used a Windows machine with a misconfigured Git that "helpfully" changed newlines to Windows CRLFs.

Also, the screenshot of your error clearly has different code than just that `print()`. I don't think Python prints out "END OF TIME" by default.

---

If you want to learn Python, then use a precompiled version. Since you're using Ubuntu 20.04, just

```
apt install python3-dev
```

to get all of the bits and pieces you need to work with Python and write Python extensions too.

If you really do want to compile CPython from source, e.g. to hack on its internals, then you really should use a git checkout of it – if for nothing else, to keep track of your own local changes.

Comment: First: I use the book
CPython Internals: Your Guide to the Python 3 Interpreter by Anthony Shaw
I just did what the book said

and yeah my friend cloned from Windows

and those printf's are added by me

but anyway, thank u @AKX

Comment: So... you've modified the CPython source to add some printfs, and it breaks? That's why you should have your modifications in version control, so you can easily pinpoint the changes that break things.

Comment: But please, if you're working with a book that's geared for the Python 3.9 interpreter, _at least start from Python 3.9 source_, not some other version?!

Comment: No, the code broke way before I added those printfs
I was trying to pinpoint where it breaks

Comment: Your post implies that when you just extract + compile + run Python, it breaks without any changes done. If that's not the case, then you should show the changes you've done to the source. And once again, you are working off an _unreleased version_ of Python, not 3.9.0.

Comment: Do you know caused this? the bug
Assume that I never touched the code
What could possibly make this happen? @AKX

Comment: Assuming your system is otherwise intact (e.g. hardware okay, system libraries okay, compiler okay, etc.), I would assume an unmodified Python 3.9.0 compiled from source would not crash like that.